# Combining nested lists and removing duplicates

Tags: python, list

Hoping to get some help on a newbie question. I want to sort through a bunch of sublists and if any items inside of the sublists appear twice, remove them, and merge the values in their respective lists into a new sublist.

As an example:

```
my_currentlist = [[A,B],[C,D],[B,E]]
my_desiredlist = [[A,E],[C,D]]
```

Any ideas?

My failed attempt (sorry, new to python):

```
for i in range(len(items)):
    j=i+1
    for j in range(len(items)):
        if items[i][0]==items[j][0]:
            items.remove(items[i])
            items.remove(items[j])
            items.append([items[i][1], items[j][1]])
        elif items[i][0]==items[j][1]:
            items.remove(items[i])
            items.remove(items[j])
            items.append([items[i][1], items[j][0]])
        elif items[i][1]==items[j][0]:
            items.remove(items[i])
            items.remove(items[j])
            items.append([items[i][0], items[j][1]])
        elif items[i][1]==items[j][1]:
            items.remove(items[i])
            items.remove(items[j])
            items.append([items[i][0], items[j][0]])
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: It's not very clear what the general case of what you're trying to do should be. Do the sublists always have only two items? What would the result be for `[[A, B], [B, C], [C, A]]`? What about `[[A, A], [B, C]]`? Or `[[A, B], [C, D], [A, B]]`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Yes, the sublists in this case are always two items. For my purposes the cases you proposed would never occur. An item could only occur a maximum of two times throughout the entire list.

Comment: Sorry, having trouble posting what I've tried with correct formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a double loop, the first one to take one element (sublist) from the list, and the second one to check the presence of its the elements in the rest of the sublist

this should do the trick

```
>>> my_currentlist = [["A","B"],["C","D"],["B","E"]]
>>> my_desiredlist = []
>>> while my_currentlist:
        a,b = my_currentlist.pop(0)
        for i,temp in enumerate(my_currentlist):
            if a in temp:
                temp.remove(a)
                a = temp[0]
                my_currentlist.pop(i)
                break
            elif b in temp:
                temp.remove(b)
                b = temp[0]
                my_currentlist.pop(i)
                break
        my_desiredlist.append( [a,b] )

>>> my_desiredlist
[['A', 'E'], ['C', 'D']]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you Copperfield! This is exactly what I needed. Also helped me learn the syntax better.